# how to write decimal numbers as an atomic write in F#?

Tags: multithreading, f#, decimal

the decimal type takes 128 bits, so it is not naturally an atomic write.

I tried:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref myField, some new value)
```

but then I saw that decimal is not part of the supported types with Interlocked.Exchange.

I was thinking that doing a lock may be a little bit heavy for this write. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `Interlocked.Exchange` can only work with 32bit or 64bit values, so it does not support `decimal`. Aside from using locks, one suggestion [from a related C# StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719770/interlocked-exchange-nullable-decimal) is to wrap the value in an object and then use `Interlocked.Exchange` to swap the object references. In F#, this would look like this:

```
type Boxed<'T when 'T : struct>(v:'T) = 
  member x.Value = v

let mutable d1 = Boxed(1M)
let d2 = Boxed(2M)

Interlocked.Exchange(&d1, d2)
```

The question is whether the overhead of an additional instance is greater than the overhead of using `lock` - I think this will depend on your specific case. If you have just a few decimals that you're working with, the extra objects may not be such a big deal, but you'll probably need to run some tests to find out.